# Fourier transform of cross-spectral density space matrix elements

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

In order to derive phase space like equation of motion (e.g. the equation of motion for the Wigner function of a single particle in one-dimension), it is an advantage to work with the Fourier transform ([Schleich](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/352729435X), Sec. D.2:

$$
 t^{(\pm)}(\hat{A}) = \frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi e^{-ip\xi/\hbar}\mathcal{M}^{\pm}(x,\xi) \, ,
$$

where in this case I want to consider

$$
\mathcal{M}^{+}(x,\xi) = \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} - 2\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^ 2} \right)\langle x+\xi/2|\hat{A}|x-\xi/2\rangle \, .
$$

Now, in order to compute this $t^+$, the author says that we have to integrate by parts the partial derivatives with respect to $\xi$. For instance

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi e^{-ip\xi/\hbar} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^ 2}\langle x+\xi/2|\hat{A}|x-\xi/2\rangle \, .
$$

If I integrate by parts as suggested, why

$$
e^{-ip\xi/\hbar} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\langle x+\xi/2|\hat{A}|x-\xi/2\rangle
$$

evaluates to zero when evaluated in the limits of the integral? It is not an odd function, and I can't figure out another argument why this element vanishes.

Comment: It's probably subjective, but the language is needlessly stressful here. You might try, instead, Lemma 0.3, eqn (18-20) of [this concise treatise](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), leaving the  translation via Ch 0.18 aside. I will try to do the translation between the two books, but most of the work will go into translating to a triviality...

Comment: Then... what's the rabbit at the end of the hole? Is the derivation in Schleich wrong? I didn't know your book until yesterday, a friend give me the reference. It's a pity that amazon does not have it on existence.

Comment: PS the Fourier transform of the Wigner function is the cross-spectral density, $\tilde {f} (x,\xi)= \psi^* (x-\xi/2) \psi(x+\xi/2)$, and, as in our Lemma, it leads to the star-genvalue equations from Schroedinger's --or Heisenberg's--and, importantly, *vice versa*!

Comment: Woops, it was only the hardbound, which is still odd indeed for amazon.

Comment: Sure, but still I have to get used to the star product that you work with. Still, I think that the term that I mention is zero. Schleich does the same but now in p82. He states: "In order to secure the existence of the Fourier transform the boundary terms have to banish". I think this is exactly the same case that I ask.

Comment: I usually wait a couple of days to see if someone else answers.

Comment: Oh, but this is the non-boundary residue of the integration by parts you are talking about...   Everything attenuates to 0 at the boundary, as the quantities are (mostly) local.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll parallel your book's proof in my language of Lemma 3 in our [booklet](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), but now for the off-diagonal Wigner function,  setting $\hbar=1$ , easy to reinstate by dimensional analysis.

The time dependence is a canard, taken up at the very end: the crucial piece, including Wolfgang's integration by parts, visible further below, is for the *stationary* Wigner function,
$$
W_{E~E'}(x,p)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int dy e^{-iyp} \tilde f(x,y),
$$
where the all-central cross-spectral density amounts to 
$$
 \tilde f(x,y)=\langle x+y/2| (|E' \rangle\langle E|)|x-y/2 \rangle \\ =\psi^*_E (x-y/2)~~\psi_{E'} (x+y/2),
$$
for TISE,
$$
\left (-\frac{1}{2m} \partial_x^2 + V(x)\right ) \psi_E (x) = E \psi_E (x).
$$

Thus, by virtue of our eqn (12), the celebrated Bopp shift, 
\begin{eqnarray}             
&& ~~~~H(x,p)\star W_{EE'}(x,p)= \nonumber \\
&=& {1\over 2\pi} \left( \frac{1}{2m}\left( p-{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x \right) ^2  
+V(x) \right) \int\! dy~ e^{-iy(p+{i\over2}  \overleftarrow {\partial }_x)}
  \tilde f(x,y) \nonumber  \\ 
&=& {1\over 2\pi} \int\! dy~ e^{-iyp} ~ \left(\frac{1}{2m} \left( p-{i\over2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x\right) ^2 
+V(x+y/2)\right)     \tilde f(x,y)   \nonumber \\
&=& {1\over 2\pi} \int\! dy ~e^{-iyp} 
\left( \frac{1}{2m}\left( i\overrightarrow{\partial }_y +{i\over2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x\right) ^2 
+ V(x+ y/2)\right)  
\psi^*_E(x-  y/2) ~\psi_{E'}(x+  y/2)  \nonumber 
\\ &=& {1\over 2\pi} \int\! dy ~e^{-iyp} \psi^*(x-  y/2)~
E'~ \psi(x+  y/2)  = E' ~W_{EE'}(x,p)~.   
\end{eqnarray}
The Fourier integration by parts yields the penultimate line, as the surface terms vanish: all wavefunctions, potentials, etc, are assumed to vanish at infinity. In the penultimate line, the operators only Schroedinger-act on the $\psi$, leaving the $\psi^*$ alone! (Think of left- versus right-movers.)

Mutatis mutandis, 
$$
  W_{EE'}(x,p) \star H (x,p)= E W_{EE'}(x,p). 
$$
So, then 
$$
 W_{EE'}  \star H (x,p) + H\star W_{EE'}= (E+E') W_{EE'} ,
$$
and 
$$
 W_{EE'}  \star H (x,p) - H\star W_{EE'}= (E-E') W_{EE'} ,
$$
for these stationary Wigner functions. Consequently, for the time-dependent ones,
$$
{\cal W}_{EE'}(x,p;t) = e^{i(E-E')t} W_{EE'}(x,p),
$$
one gets Moyal's evolution equation for the Wigner function, the Wigner transform of the von Neumann equation,
$$
  H\star {\cal W}_{EE'}- {\cal W}_{EE'}  \star H (x,p)= i\partial _t   {\cal W}_{EE'}.
  $$

To compare with Wofgang's Summary D.5, first take into consideration our somewhat dyslexic adherence to Moyal's notation which reverses Schleich's *E' E* ordering; and further recall our stationary equations above amount to just 
$$
 W_{EE'}  \star H (x,p) + H\star W_{EE'}\\ =  \Biggl ( H \left (\left( x+{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_p \right) ,\left( p-{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x \right) \right ) +  H \left (\left( x-{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_p \right) ,\left( p+{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x \right) \right ) \Biggr )  W_{EE'}(x,p)\\ =(E+E') W_{EE'},
$$
and the corresponding one for the (-) equation that enters the Moyal evolution equation in phase space,
$$
\Biggl (- H \left (\left( x+{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_p \right) ,\left( p-{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x \right) \right ) +  H \left (\left( x-{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_p \right) ,\left( p+{i\over 2} \overrightarrow{\partial }_x \right) \right ) \Biggr )  W_{EE'}(x,p)\\ =(E-E') W_{EE'}.
$$

A ready check is looking at the fate of the kinetic term quadratic in the *p*s, etc... The fastidious practice of resolving the translation operators through infinite (Taylor) sums started with Wigner and has not abandoned some educators.

- The takeaway, emphasized by Fairlie in 1964, is that Moyal's equation does not suffice to determine the Wigner function completely, but relies on the above (+) equation as well. This has its analog in Hilbert space: solutions *ρ* of the von Neumann equation are not fully determined, unless their anticommutator with the hamiltonian is also fixed by an eigenvalue (+) equation.